# Name of area between two parallel lines

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, terminology, euclidean-geometry

Assume that there are two distinct parallel lines on a Euclidean plane. Is there a name for the zone between these two lines?

Comment: Thanks for suggesting Math.StackExchange as an alternative venue for this question. I agree that this is a relatively basic question about terminology. In this case it so happens that it did arise during research activities.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Strip*.

This is how it is used in complex analysis, where strips are common (as domains for various transcendental functions). I have seen the same term in other contexts...

Comment: Thanks! For posterity, Springer's Encyclopedia of Mathematics [entry for "strip"](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Strip).